# Complete HTTP GET with scapy

Tags: python, http, html-parsing, packet, scapy

I am trying to use scapy to run a complete HTTP session. That is to say, I want to manually perform the three way handshake, GET request, acknowledgements as necessary to receive the HTML file, and terminating the connection. Using [1] I have completed the three way handshake and the GET request, but I can't seem to capture the raw HTML packets sent from the server, and I obviously can't send an ack packet back for more. Any ideas?

Additionally, I'd ultimately like to be able to parse the raw packet for HTML. If anyone knows how to do that from a scapy packet I'd appreciate it.

[1] http://www.thice.nl/creating-ack-get-packets-with-scapy/

Answer (score 2):

Gimbi,

I am at work and can only parse and not initiate connections in scapy right now. So i will address your second request. We are looking at something like I have provided here. The layer that contains the html as well as the http requests is (Raw).load if the packet contains html or an http request I would first test to see if the layer exists (haslayer) and then if the packet is a 'http packet" here is  just check for 80 in the IF statement, however you could potentially just use the port in the sniff netfilter. I have included the option to sniff directly off the wire or pull in a pcap here in this snippet. (adjust ports etc if you are using non standards)

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

from scapy import *
import sys

def parse(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(TCP) and pkt.getlayer(TCP).dport == 80 and pkt.haslayer(Raw):
        print pkt.getlayer(Raw).load

if '-l' in sys.argv:
    sniff(prn=parse)

else:
    pkts = rdpcap(sys.argv[1])
    for pkt in pkts:
       parse(pkt)
```

Of course use this as a start you can adjust  line 8 to  pick up not just dport but also sport for example. Let me know if this helps at all and good luck!

**P.S. change the following**

```
from scapy import *
```

to

```
from scapy.all import *
```

depending on your version..